# Set description attribute in action on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is it posible to set description on action? If it was possible, how can I get the description?

example :

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{
    [Description("Description Test")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do yo uneed this description for? What do you expect the attribute to do? Why can't you use comments?

Comment: Where will this Description be used?

Comment: i want to use it for storage on database, so my partner will know what action i have on the controller specifically and for some authorize purpose, because the role will be flexsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, First you need to define an attribute then using reflection for extracting its information:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
    public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private readonly string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
        }

        public DescriptionAttribute(string title)
        {
            _title = title;
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetDisplayName(this MemberInfo target)
        {
            return target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)
                .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>().Select(d => d.Title)
                .SingleOrDefault() ?? target.Name;
        }
    }
```

And use it this way:

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{
    [Description("Description Test")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can extract the information using reflection this way:

```
var controllers =
                typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom).Where(method => method.IsPublic &&  method.IsDefined(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true));
```

Comment: is there a way to get the "Description Test"? I'm using typeof(TestingController ).GetProperty("Index").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) but resulting on System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: @hartono I've updated my answer